# Proof of countable family of finite sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Definition: A set $A$ is countable if there exists a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$.
NOTE: According to the definition I'm using, countable = countably infinite.

Definition: A set is at most countable if it is finite or countable.

Let $(A_i)_i$ be a countable family of finite sets such that the family contains non-empty terms. Then $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$  is countable.

My proof:
As $(A_i)_i$ is a family of countable sets, we may enumerate the family as a sequence ($A_1,A_2,A_3....$) such that each term is distinct. Let $A_1$ $=(a_{11},a_{21},a_{31}…,a_{n1})$. So for an arbitrary j, we may enumerate the elements of $A_j$ as $(a_{1j},a_{2j}…,a_{m_{j}j})$.
How should I enumerate the union?

Comment: Just an FYI: The way you define countable is usually known as countably infinite. The standard definition of countable is what you call at most countable: i.e., there exists an injection from set $A\to\mathbb N$.

Comment: The proof is on the right track, I just think it's a bit too handwavy at points.

Comment: @DonThousand may you please elaborate?

Comment: 'As each $_i$ is distinct, we will be left with infinitely many distinct elements and therefore the union is countable." - too vague

Comment: @DonThousan $A_i\neq A_j$ for $i\neq j$ and we have countably infinite of them. How should I make this more clear?

Comment: How are you enumerating the union? That's the hard part of the proof, which you basically glossed over. Point is, there are several parts of this proof which have the right idea, but are too vague, or ignore the complexity of the problem.

Comment: @DonThousand ahh, I see your point. I understand why its vague. I'm not quite sure how to enumerate the union.

Comment: That's the fun part of the proof :)

Comment: Agree with Don:  when you say "enumerate the union", you are effectively already assuming that the union is countable (enumerable is really the same thing as countable) but that's exactly what you need to show. That is, you need to show that you *can* enumerate the union.

Answer (score 1):

Prove the contrapositive (or arrive at a contradiction) using the pigeon-hole principle.

It should be clear the $U=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ is "at most countable", i.e. it is either finite or countable (=countably infinite). You want to rule out the possibility that $U$ is finite.
Clearly $A_n\subseteq U$ for every $n$. If $U$ were finite then its power-set
$\mathcal P(U):=\{V:V\subseteq U\}$ would also be finite. (This just says that $2^n$ is a natural number whenever $n$ is.) But every $A_n$ is an element of $\mathcal P(U)$, and we cannot have infinitely many distinct elements in a finite set.

Edit. Just trying to comment on your question as to how to enumerate the union, starting with your suggestion that $A_j=(a_{1j},a_{2j}…,a_{m_j j})$. You could make the additional assumption that for each $j$ there is $k_j$ with $0\le k_j\le m_j$ such that if $n\le k_j$ then $a_{n,j}$ does not belong to any $A_i$ with $i<j$, and on the other hand if $k_j<n\le m_j$ then $a_{n,j}$ belongs to at least one $A_i$ with $i<j$.

Just to clarify this notation, if $k_j=m_j$ then all elements of $A_j$ are "new", i.e they do not appear in any "earlier" $A_i$'s (with $i<j$). On the other hand, if $k_j=0$ then none of the elements of $A_j$ is "new", i.e each element of $A_j$ is already an element of $A_i$'s for some $i<j$ (where $i$ need not be unique and may depend on the particular element of $A_j$).

Since the family $(A_i)_i$ is countably infinite, there are infinitely many $j$ with $k_j\ge1$. (Hint for this part. If there were a largest $j$ with $k_j\ge1$ then let $B=\bigcup_{i\le j}A_i$. Then $B$ is finite and hence has only finitely many subsets, but on the other hand every $A_i$ with $i>j$ is one of these finitely many sets, a contradiction.)

Let $J=\{j:k_j\ge1\}=\{j_1,j_2,j_3,...\}$ where $j_1<j_2<j_3<...$
Then $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ can be listed as
$(a_{1j_1},…,a_{k_{j_1} j_1},a_{1j_2},…,a_{k_{j_2} j_2},a_{1j_3},…,a_{k_{j_3} j_3},…)$

Answer (score 0):

With these definitions, the assertion is false as stated: just let $A_n=\emptyset$ for all $n$. Or, more generally, fix a finite set $U$ and choose every $A_n$ to be a subset of $U$.

Comment: Ok. Suppose $A_n$ is non-empty. If U is finite, then it has finite many subsets. I'm assuming that each subset is distinct and that I have countably infinite of them.

Comment: That clarification makes the assertion both true and interesting. I recommend that you edit the original post to make the statement clear. By the way, you've pretty much just outlined a proof (by contradiction) of the statement!

Comment: i'm really not sure what to do next.

Comment: @topologicalmagician Next, follow Greg Martin's advice and edit your question to make it clear that the $A_n$ are supposed to be distinct.